# Adjective that means "Full of Integrity"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that means "full of integrity." I can only think of 'integruous' which is 100% made up. I regularly seek for this word when trying to identify people as having integrity, or decisions being made with integrity. For use in a sentence such as "She is a/n 'integrous' woman." Or "If you want to be more highly respected, ensure that your actions are 'integruous.'"

Comment: Would "[virtuous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtuous)" do? Meaning 2 in the link (MW) states "Morally excellent" - is that close enough? EDIT: Also, "[probity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probity)" (MW) may be a very good fit.

Comment: @Spratty You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Hank - I would have done but for the life of me I cannot think of an adjectival form of "probity" which would have been my preferred answer. That's life, I suppose.

Comment: I feel like virtuous has a moral quality that integrous lacks - and sometimes (such as in a business setting) it's better without the moral baggage.

Answer (score 10):

Merriam-Webster [defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upstanding) **upstanding** as "full of integrity".

You could also use **principled**, which is circularly [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principled) as "characterized by principle"; and "principle", in turn, [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principle) "a rule or code of conduct" in this context.

Answer (score 6):

The word *[integrous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/integrous)* exists since at least the 19th century, but according to Wiktionary:

> Most speakers and writers opt for an etymologically unrelated synonym — such as honest, decent, or virtuous — when trying to express an adjectival equivalent of integrity.

My personal preference is *[upright](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upright)*.

Comment: I like this as the answer, let's bring back integrous!

Answer (score 5):

The first definition of *integrity* in wiktionary is

> Steadfast adherence to a strict moral or ethical code.

Therefore I think [**ethical**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethical#English) fits. A person with integrity is an ethical person. If you want to be more highly respected, make ethical decisions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most commonly employed form, and the one I prefer is simply ***person of integrity***.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve been saying “integrial or integritous”.

Answer (score -1):

**Honest**
You are a person of your word